# Problems using TextBoxFor with viewModels in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel, html.textboxfor

I recently started to use a viewModel. Here's the viewModel I am using:

```
public class ContentViewModel
    {
        public Content Content { get; set; }
        public bool UseRowKey { 
            get {
                return Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" ||
                   Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06";
            }
        }
        public string TempRowKey { get; set; }

    }
```

I changed my razor views from:

```
@model WebUx.Content

<div class="colx2-left">
    <label for="complex-fr-url" class="required">Order</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Order)
</div>
```

to:

```
@model WebUx.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Contents.ContentViewModel

<div class="colx2-left">
    <label for="complex-fr-url" class="required">Order</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Content.Order)
</div>
```

Now my views fail with the following message:

> Compiler Error Message: 
>   CS0411: The type arguments for method System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor TModel,TProperty>
>   (System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>)
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Can someone give me advice about what I should do?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the Content class?

Comment: Yes please show us what the Content class has too

Comment: anyone seeing this comment, **make sure by adding the model**, i used DB first in MVC and didn't generate the model and wasted time.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, i ensure my Views/templates only reference a property within the model it's dealing with, not one under.

Your first attempt before your change was correct.

So, i would change your View to the following:

```
@model WebUx.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Contents.ContentViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
```

And make use of your existing template:

```
@model WebUx.Content
<div class="colx2-left">
    <label for="complex-fr-url" class="required">Order</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Order)
</div>
```

Also i have no idea about what `Order` is. If it's not a string, then that's also going to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `Order` is a *public* property on `Content`. Right now I got this exception while implementing a [POC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) app. Guess what? I forgot to add the [public specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h05xxt5d.aspx) in front of my ViewModel properties.

I had this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [StringLength(16)]
    string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(18, 65)]
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and then that same exception you got was being thrown here.

I did this to fix the problem:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [StringLength(16)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(18, 65)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```